# a git script to checkout in batch

Tags: git

Recently, I find a kind of git script looks like following, which is named "script" (let say) and can be called by script-checkout. Then all projects can be pulled to local. Does anyone know what is and how to write such script, or could give me a reference link?

```
git ; my-dir ; https://bitbucket.myrepository.com/myproject.git ; b:my-branch
git ; my-dir2 ; https://bitbucket.myrepository.com/myproject2.git ; b:my-branch
git ; my-dir3 ; https://bitbucket.myrepository.com/myproject3.git ; b:my-branch
```